# Can we add multiple endpoints in single instance of nodejs circuit breaker pattern in microservice architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, microservices

I want to wrap all my endpoints in single instance of circuitbreaker

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would pass them as an array argument to your function.

```
function myResilientFunction(arr){
 ...
}
```